# DBI::dbSendQuery fails with RJDBC::JDBC for SQL SERVER

Tags: r, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc, rjdbc

When I run the insert statement with **odbc** driver everythings fine.

```
drv <- odbc::odbc()
conn <- createConn(drv, trusted_connection = T, dsn="mydsn", uid="myuid", pwd="mypwd")
DBI::dbSendQuery("INSERT INTO \"dbo\".\"testjdbc\" (d) values('4')")
```

When I run the select statement with **jdbc** everything is fine too:

```
   drv <- RJDBC::JDBC(driverClass = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", classPath = "C:\\mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar") 
    conn <- DBI::dbConnect(drv, trusted_connection = T, url = "jdbc:sqlserver://myserver\\\\myinstance:1111;databaseName=mydatabasename", user="myuid", password="mypwd") 
    DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, "Select * from dbo.mytable")
```

and the connection for **jdbc** is valid:

```
drv <- RJDBC::JDBC(driverClass = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", classPath = "C:\\mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar") 
        conn <- DBI::dbConnect(drv, trusted_connection = T, url = "jdbc:sqlserver://myserver\\\\myinstance:1111;databaseName=mydatabasename", user="myuid", password="mypwd") 
    DBI::dbIsValid(conn) # TRUE
```

But when I try insert statement (the same like the first one) with **jdbc** driver like this:

```
drv <- RJDBC::JDBC(driverClass = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", classPath = "C:\\mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar") 
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(drv, trusted_connection = T, url = "jdbc:sqlserver://myserver\\\\myinstance:1111;databaseName=mydatabasename", user="myuid", password="mypwd") 
DBI::dbSendQuery(conn, "INSERT INTO \"dbo\".\"testjdbc\" (d) values('4')")
```

then I get the error:

```
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for INSERT INTO "dbo"."testjdbc" (d) values('4') (The statement did not return a result set.)
```

So **jdbc** select is OK but inserts, updates, deletes gives errors while with **odbc** I can do everything.

Comment: An insert statement is not a query (it does not produce a result set). Use a method to execute non-queries. I don't know RJDBC, so I can't help you identifying the right method: check its API documentation.

Comment: but with the odbc driver everything works fine...

Comment: It all depends on what happens below the surface, and JDBC has a strict separation between executing result-set producing statements and other statements. Given the exception RJDBC calls `executeQuery` on a JDBC statement, which is not allowed for statements that don't produce result sets. Maybe it is different for ODBC.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to run inserts not with `DBI::dbSendQuery` but with `RJDBC::dbSendUpdate`.

Thank you @Mark Rotteveel  for your answer. Thanks to you I have found the solution.